# SQLite extremely slow via C-API

Tags: sqlite

Using SQLite 3.19.2, I'm running into an odd situation.

One of the queries my application performs takes an enormously long time (100+ seconds) when running inside my app. Using the sqlite3 shell, the same query takes 0.5s.

I'm using a custom build of SQLite, statically linked into my app. The version of the shell is from my custom compilation, so this isn't an issue with the compilation.

I was using multiple threads however I've since managed to reproduce this issue single-threaded.

Using `perf` I've determined that the majority of the CPU time is spent in `sqlite3VdbeExec` and not in any of my code (for instance code that reads the fields of each returned row.)

The query is `sqlite3_prepare_v2`'d with bound parameters. I've reproduced the query below as well as a similar query that doesn't exhibit the performance problem.

Has anyone else seen anything like this?

---

SLOW QUERY (100+s in the app, 0.5s in the shell):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Track.*
FROM
    TrackGenres,
    TrackFirstArtist,
    Track
WHERE
    TrackFirstArtist.id = Track.id AND
    TrackGenres.id = Track.id AND
    TrackGenres.genreID = 328
ORDER BY
    (CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN TrackFirstArtist.artistName COLLATE ENGLISH END) ASC,
    (CASE WHEN 1 != 1 THEN TrackFirstArtist.artistName COLLATE ENGLISH END) DESC
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0;
```

QUERY PLAN (the plans are identical for whether run in the app or in the shell):

```
2 0 0 SEARCH TABLE TrackGenre USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_TrackGenre_1 (genreID=?)
3 0 1 SEARCH TABLE WorkGenre USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_WorkGenre_1 (genreID=?)
3 1 0 SEARCH TABLE TrackWork USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_TrackWork_1 (workID=?)
1 0 0 COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 2 AND 3 USING TEMP B-TREE (UNION)
4 0 0 SCAN TABLE TrackArtist USING INDEX idx_TrackArtist_trackID
4 1 1 SEARCH TABLE Artist USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0 0 0 SCAN SUBQUERY 1
0 1 2 SEARCH TABLE Track USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0 2 1 SEARCH SUBQUERY 4 USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (id=?)
0 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
0 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

---

SIMILAR QUERY (0.5s in app, 0.5s in shell):

```
SELECT
    COUNT (Track.id)
FROM
    TrackGenres,
    TrackFirstArtist,
    Track
WHERE
    TrackFirstArtist.id = Track.id AND
    TrackGenres.id = Track.id AND
    TrackGenres.genreID = 328 AND
    ( TrackFirstArtist.artistName >= 'a' AND TrackFirstArtist.artistName < 'b' );
```

Comment: Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) in both cases.

Comment: Also, are you running your app under a debugger?

Comment: @Cameron: No, I'm not running under a debugger.

Comment: @CL: I'll update to include that info, I hadn't considered the possibility that the query plan could be different in the app vs. in the shell.

Comment: The VDBE is the opcodes for the small virtual machine that executes the compiled query. If the query plan is different, the VDBE will be different, and that could be the source of the difference.

Comment: @Cameron: Ok, but why would the query plan differ between an app and the shell built against the same static library?

Comment: @Tim: No idea. Perhaps the data is slightly different? Or the connection settings?

Comment: @CL.: I added the query plan for the slow query. Unfortunately it is identical whether run from my app or from the shell.

Comment: Show the definitions of the view(s). And that ORDER BY looks suspicious; does dropping the COLLATE help, or removing one of the CASEs?

Comment: @CL. I'm less concerned about trying to optimize the query itself than I am in trying to understand why it is running 216x slower when executed from within my app vs. when executed within the sqlite3 shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in `SQLite`. I tracked the problem down to the `CASE` statements in the `ORDER BY` clause when using the query in a prepared statement.

When I removed one or the other of the statements, the query ran quickly again. The collation didn't make any difference.

This doesn't seem to be a general issue with prepared statements, I have other queries with a similar structure and they work properly. As such, I've been unable to create a simple, reproducible example that illustrates the problem.

Ultimately I had to solve this by replacing the variables in the query manually to avoid the use of a prepared statement.